# Is there a norm that can specify an unique vector $x$?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, normed-spaces

Assume that we have a vector $x$ with dimension $3$. The value of $x = {4, 2, 8}$.
My question is if there is a norm that can generate one value of $x$ that are unique compared to other samples of $x$.

For example. Using $L^2$ norm generates the same number if we have two $x$ e.g $x_1 = {-4, 2, 8}$ and $x_2 = {4, 2, 8}$.

$$||x_1||_2 = ||x_2||_2$$

And if I'm using another values of $x$ e.g $x_3 = {8, 2, 4}$ then $L^1$ norm would be the same for $$||x_2||_1 = ||x_3||_1$$

So is there a norm that can create a very unique number of a random vector $x$?

Comment: The answer is clearly no, which you can show by the triangle inequality, since the norm generates a metric.

Comment: There are functions that give a one-one map from ordered triples to real numbers, but they aren't norms.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you show me?

Comment: @DonThousand So there is no unique number who can represent a specific vector?

Comment: @Martensson As Gerry said, there is a way of identifying triples of reals with the reals, but none that are norms.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes, I know that. But which one?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I can't think of a nice one. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126069/bijection-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2) does two dimensions to one dimension, but you can compose it with itself to make a map from 3 dimensions to 1 dimension.

Comment: Given reals $a+r$, $b+s$, $c+t$, with $a,b,c$ integers, and $r,s,t$ all between zero and one, you can map it to the real with integer part $2^a3^b5^c$, and as for the fractional part, if $r,s,t$ are given by $.r_1r_2r_3\dots$, $.s_1s_2s_3\dots$, $.t_1t_2t_3\dots$, then you form $.r_1s_1t_1r_2s_2t_2\dots$. This is OK if $a,b,c$ are all positive; if $a<0$ then multiply the integer part by $7$; $b<0$, by $11$; $c<0$ by $13$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment, Daniel?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sounds difficult, sorry.

Comment: OK. Given the triple $(\pi,-e,-\sqrt2)=(3.14159\dots,-2.71828\dots,-1.41421\dots)$, rewrite as $(3+.14159\dots,-3+.28171\dots,-2+.58578\dots)$, and map to the real number $2^33^35^2(11)(13)+.125488115577918\dots=772200.125488115577918\dots$, OK?

Comment: Isin't it easier to use binary instead?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you can write that answer :)

Comment: I'll make it an answer soon. But what makes binary easier than decimal?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because decimals in practice is sensitive.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because 4.23254543 may work for my computer, but not yours.

Comment: OK, I wouldn't know about that, but everything works if you use binary. I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to construct a one-one map from the set of all ordered triples of reals to the reals:

Write your triple of reals as $(a+r,b+s,c+t)$ with $a,b,c$ integers and $r,s,t$ between zero (inclusive) and one (exclusive). Map it to the real whose integer part is $2^{|a|}3^{|b|}5^{|c|}7^d11^e13^f$ where $d$ (respectively, $e$, $f$) is zero if $a$ (respectively $b$, $c$) is at least zero; otherwise, one; and the decimal part is obtained by interleaving the digits of $r,s,t$. That is, if $r=.r_1r_2\dots$, $s=.s_1s_2\dots$, $t=.t_1t_2\dots$, then you form $.r_1s_1t_1r_2s_2t_2\dots$.

For example, given the triple $(\pi,-e,-sqrt2)=(3.14159\dots,-2.71828\dots,-1.41421\dots)$, rewrite it as $(3+.14159\dots,-3+.28171\dots,-2+58578)$, and map it to $2^33^35^2\times11\times13+.125488115577918\dots=772200.125488115577918\dots$.

you could do the same thing in binary, or any base you like.